# After adding a modulo to function, all outputs are zero

Tags: python, fibonacci, modulo

I wrote a program to calculate Fibonacci numbers, and it works fine.  Then I altered the program to give me the Fibonacci numbers modulo 65536, and all my output became zeros.  What went wrong?

```
import time
def fib_matrix_timed(min):
    timeout = time.time() + 60*min
    A = [0, 1]
    i = 1
    while time.time() < timeout:
        try:
            B = A
            A[0] = B[1]
            A[1] = ((B[0] + B[1])%65536)
            print A[0]
            i+=1
        except OverflowError:
            print "fib_iterative overflows at ", i
    print A[0]
    print "fib_matrix calculated ", i, "iterations in", min, "minute(s)"

fib_matrix_timed(1)
```

Comment: Printing `B` instead of `A[0]` in the loop shows: `[0, 1]`,
`[1, 2]`,
`[2, 4]`,
`[4, 8]`,
`[8, 16]`,
`[16, 32]`,
`[32, 64]`,
`[64, 128]`,
`[128, 256]`,
`[256, 512]`,
`[512, 1024]`,
`[1024, 2048]`,
`[2048, 4096]`,
`[4096, 8192]`,
`[8192, 16384]`,
`[16384, 32768]`,
`[32768, 0]`,
`[0, 0]`, printing out 0 from there onwards, of course.  This ties in with the list in B being a reference to the list in A, rather than a separate copy of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is:

```
B = A
```

Lists in python are [mutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), which means when you do this, A is the same object as B, rather than a new list. So whenever you change either list A or list B, you are effectively changing both lists at the same time.

This line could instead be:

```
B = [A[0], A[1]]
```

Or: (suggestion by MarcosModenesi)

```
B = A[:] # works for list of any size containing immutable objects
```

Instead of making B just a reference to the same object as A, this would create an entirely new instance, with the values of the original.

The below example illustrates the problem when B is the same list as A.

Suppose A is [0,1]:

```
B = A
```

now B is A is [0,1]

```
A[0] = B[1]
```

B[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) is 1, so now A[0] is B[0] is 1. A and B are now both [1,1].

```
A[1] = (B[0] + B[1]) % 65536
```

A and B are now [1,2]

The sequence thus generated is 1,2,4,8,16,32....

Since 65536 is 2^16, i.e. the 17th number in the sequence, of course the modulo would be 2^16 * 2^n % 2^16 = 0.

The problem arises from incorrect instantiation of list B, causing the sequence generated to be incorrect.

Comment: That looks plausible, but doesn't really explain why it works with `A[1] = (B[0] + B[1])` instead of `A[1] = ((B[0] + B[1])%65536)`.

Comment: True, Jonathan.  However, icedtrees suggestion did fix the problem.

Comment: An easier way, getting rid of enumerating all items in the new list (which could be many more) is `B = A[:] `

Comment: @MarcosModenesi Thanks, I included your suggestion

Comment: So I see...thanks.  I added a similar comment, having come to the same conclusion.  You get the up-vote.

Comment: Just a pet peeve: the fact that `B = A` does not copy A is not because A is mutable.  `B = A` never copies A regardless of whether A is mutable.  `A` being mutable means that *it matters* whether a copy is made or not.

Comment: @BrenBarn You are right. Hopefully the new wording of the answer is ok